# Introducir datos en una tabla, de otra tabla

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

Estoy creando un sistema de logeo en PHP, y hasta el momento la tabla de registro funciona a la perfección. Registro tiene atributos como el id autoincrementado, el usuario, la contraseña y el email.

Necesito crear otra tabla llamada niveles, ya que la finalidad de la página es superar unos niveles. Esta tabla pretende tener atributos como el usuario, y los niveles, de modo que, se pueda hacer un update desde la página hacia esa tabla cada vez que alguien haya superado un nivel.

Ahora bien, no tengo ni idea de cómo podría obtener el valor 'usuario' en la tabla niveles, extrayendolo de la tabla 'Registro'.

He estado mirando sobre relaciones (tengo muy poca idea al respecto) y creo que podría ser una solución, pero por más que he intentado no he conseguido nada.

Se me ha ocurrido la chapuza de que cuándo el usuario se registre (inserte los datos en la tabla registro) también lo haga en la tabla niveles. Pero creo que realizar dos consultas sería chapucero.

En el peor de los casos lo haré así, pero solo por si acaso ¿existe alguna forma más fácil?

Gracias por las respuestas.

Comment: lo ideal es que se tengan 2 tablas una de usuarios y otra de niveles; donde niveles puede tener id, nombre_nivel y usuarios tener id usuario_nombre y id_nivel donde id_nivel se convierte en la llave foránea que vincula a la tabla usuarios con la tabla niveles de modo que al final un usuario puede tener un nivel

Comment: Hola, disculpa la molestia. @ShadowPaz. 

No entiendo muy bien el sistema de relaciones, hasta dónde yo pensaba creía que, si tenia usuarios como varchar y clave primaria, y en niveles el usuario como varchar y foranea, en cascada, ésta traeria automáticamente lo registrado en la tabla registros.

Mi idea no es solo tener una columna en cuánto a niveles sino varíos, ya que constaría de varios niveles dónde necesito evaluar si uno ya fue o no pasado (para el sistema de puntuación).

Sin embargo, ahora que mencionas que en registro debería haber id_nivel, me he quedado totalmente en blanco

Comment: te postee una respuesta espero sea de ayuda

Comment: Hola Sharki Aragon, bienvenido a Stack Overflow, te sugiero completar el [recorrido del sitio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del lugar y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También puedes revisar la sección de **[como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)** para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad.